# `Color` property isn't being applied to TWebPanel component in a TMS Web Core Website

Tags: css, delphi, background-color, tms, tms-web-core

I have a `TWebPanel` component that has its `Color` property set to `clTeal`, but when I run the project then I don't see the `Color` property being applied.

Here's it in design-time with the correct `Color` being shown:

[image: Delphi TWebPanel]

So you would expect that it would work in run-time since it's showing fine in design-time, but then during run-time in the browser, there isn't any `background-color` applied to the panel. The whole panel is just transparent with no color:

[image: TMS Web Project in the Browser]

Comment: Isn't the main point of these images to show the _image,_ not the code, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out, but basically for some reason if you add an `ElementClassName` to your component, then it ignores a bunch of properties and simply don't apply them.

So because I have a Bootstrap `rounded` class applied to my panel, it doesn't use the `Color` property.

---

This doesn't seem very intuitive. I would assume it would only choose the CSS from those classes.

As an example. The class I have added doesn't have any `background-color` applied to it. Therefore because it doesn't have a `background-color` applied to it, you would assume it would use the `Color` property on the panel rather.

But no. It doesn't work like this. As soon as you add a class name to it regardless of whether it has a `background-color` CSS applied to it or not, the `Color` property no longer works on the component.

---

Hopefully, this is fixed or improved in future versions of TMS Web Core, but in the meantime: You have to manually apply the CSS `background-color` property onto your panel via code instead of simply setting the `Color` property:

```
WebPanel1.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('background-color', 'teal');
```

Comment: Another day, another `.ElementHandle` answer. You could at least have linked to a bug report you (hopefully) made.